# org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor is crashing Spring-Boot application

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-boot, scheduling

We currently have a scheduled job that runs every 15 minutes. We need to have around 100 threads running. Each thread can take from 1 to 60 mins to run. The heap max size set for this application is 2g. I've been trying to configure the ThreadPoolTaskExecutor settings to get the optimal performance, but unfortunately, the application keeps crashing since the heap size keeps increasing until it reaches 2g. Below is the config for the AsyncConfigurer

```
@EnableAsync
@Configuration
public class AsyncConfig implements AsyncConfigurer {

@Bean(name = "threadPoolTaskExecutor")
public Executor threadPoolTaskExecutor() {
    ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
    executor.setCorePoolSize(50);
    executor.setMaxPoolSize(50);
    executor.setQueueCapacity(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    executor.setThreadNamePrefix("TaskExecutor-");
    executor.initialize();
    return executor;
}
```

I understand that the corePoolSize value is how many threads execute and setting the maxPoolSize to 50 is what I tried to limit the application to do. I don't care about the queue capacity because this is a background running service.

The main question is: What's the cause for the application to crash? It feels like the threads that got created never clear up after they are done with the work. Not sure what the optimal configuration would be for my scenario or if I'm missing something else.

Thank you.

Comment: you should show us the error message

Comment: This is a very broad question with a lack of details. Please add more details like what your threads are doing? Are they IO bound or CPU bound? Why do you think 2GB should be sufficient?

Comment: You've created a threadpool, so of course the threads won't "clear up". Do you really need 50 threads? The cause of your application crash is you're running out of resources. Either add more resources or modify your code to use less resources.

Comment: There are no error messages @Deadpool. I monitor the application in DataDog and I see the memory keeps increasing until it hits the 2g heap max size.

Comment: We have 100 customers. While looping through each one, I create a thread that calls a service that does some computations and uses the DB to fetch some data. I'm trying to make this job faster by creating more threads, but that is causing the application to crash because it would reach 2g in an hour. I tried increasing from 2g to 4g, it does the same behavior.